# Resolve error: webpack with invalid interface loaded as resolver after Expo upgrade to SDK 45

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, eslint

[image]

Since upgrading Expo SDK from 43 to 45, I am getting these ESLint errors in every file on the first import line. The project is able to run though.

I've tried adding the `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` package, without luck.

The error keeps coming up in every file. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing ```"settings": {
      "import/resolver": "webpack"
    },``` from your ```package.json```?

Comment: I tried removing it from `.eslintrc.js`, without luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add plugins, such as `import` and `react`.

```
plugins: [
  ...
  'import',
  'react',
],
```

**Update August `22**

Also, after receiving this error another time, I needed to remove the `@expo/webpack-config` package since using Expo bare workflow and instead install the `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` package as devDependency.

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful to be able to see the contents of your `package.json` and `eslintrc.js` files.

But as per [this issue](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1269), maybe try installing `eslint-import-resolver-webpack`?

Answer (score 0):

don't install packages separately, as above you said that you added a `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` you have to try deleting a `node-modules` folder and reinstall it again.

hope error will be solved..